# Draw tree structure in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, tree

I'm doing a school assignment to visualize in-depth search algorithm and i'd like to visualize the tree javascript creates. I've written the javascript to implement in-depth search but i'm in trouble visualizing the tree.Currently i've created an object for a node which has attributes:

```
function createNode(parent,name,suur,vaike){
    var Node = new Object();
    Node["name"]= name;
    Node["children"] = [];
    Node["parent"] = parent;

    return Node;
}
```

In general it wouldn't be really difficult to draw a tree in HTML but i would like to get my head around it before i start writing any code for visualizing. The main issues i've stated is that the length of branches have to dynamically change - if new children are added to the tree then the tree will expand so different elements wouldn't collapse.

This is an image from Wikipedia and i'd love to get something like this as a result.

[image: Tree structure]

What my question is that i'd like to get some pointers how to dynamically expand the branch lengths so that different children wouldn't collapse.

Comment: How are you going to "draw" in HTML in the first place? Canvas, SVG, HTML?

Comment: I thought maybe using different sized div-s, so HTML

Comment: So divs that are naturally nested? Then you should not need to care about collapsing. Only drawing the lines would be a bit complicated. However, I think you should just go for a structure like [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Tree_structures#/media/File:1-dimensional-range-tree.svg)

Comment: Yes, but as you can see lines between root element and two children are really long. I could just make them long but i'd like javascript to handle the size of line dynamically.

Comment: It will be very dificult to draw lines between divs only with HTML

Comment: @Anonymous0day what should i use then?

Comment: I haven't found it but i am sure to have already seen it, like a Mind Map ! i think it was with SVG but not sure ! one working example [javascript-ast](http://jointjs.com/demos/javascript-ast)

Comment: Something resurrected this question, and I found the link from @Bergi to be broken.  I think this is the correct updated version: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1-dimensional-range-tree.svg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this particular task i used [Treant.js](http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/). Really simple to use and drew nicely fitted tree. Had about 60 elements in the tree and no collision.

Here's a little snip from the result (it's scrollable, couldn't fit all on one page)

[image: snipimage]

Answer (score 1):

Below I provide a runnable snippet that creates a random tree using this class:

```
class Node {
    constructor(value, ...children) {
        this.value = value;
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

...and then turns it to an HTML table. The rendering can be customised a bit by tinkering with the CSS.

```js
function treeToHtml(tree) {
    class DisplayNode {
        constructor(node) {
            if (typeof node === "number") {
                this.width = node;
                return;
            }
            this.value = node.value;
            this.width = 1; // space at left. Excludes the width of the value-cell
            this.isRoot = true;
            this.hasLeftSibling = this.hasRightSibling = false;
            this.children = node.children.map(child => new DisplayNode(child));
            this.children.slice(1).forEach(child => child.hasLeftSibling = true);
            this.children.slice(0, -1).forEach(child => child.hasRightSibling = true);
            this.children.forEach(child => child.isRoot = false);
        }
        toString() {
            return `(${this.width})${this.value ?? ""}`
        }
        toHtml() {
            if (!this.children) return ""; // This node represents right side padding
            const left = this.hasLeftSibling ? 'class="branch"' : '';
            const right = this.hasRightSibling ? 'class="branch"' : '';
            return `${this.width > 0 ? `<td colspan="${this.width}" ${left}><\/td>` : ""}
            <td><table>
                ${this.isRoot ? "" : `<tr><td ${left}><\/td><td ${right}><\/td><\/tr>`}
                <tr><td colspan="2">${this.value}<\/td><\/tr>
                ${this.children.length ? "<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>" : ""}
            <\/table><\/td>`;
        }
    }

    const zip = (...arrays) =>
        Array.from({length: Math.min(...arrays.map(({length}) => length))}, (_, i) =>
            arrays.map(array => array[i])
        );

    const getWidth = levels => levels[0].reduce((sum, {width, value}) => sum + width + (value!=null), 0);

    function mergePair(rowsA, rowsB) {
        const pair = [rowsA, rowsB];
        const rows = zip(...pair);
        const overlap = Math.min(...rows.map(([rowA, rowB]) => rowA.at(-1).width + rowB[0].width)) - 1; 
        pair.forEach((rows, i) => {
            const indent = getWidth(rows) - overlap;
            if (indent < 0) rows.forEach(row => row.at(-i).width -= indent);
            if (indent > 0) pair[1-i].slice(rows.length).forEach(row => row.at(-i).width += indent);
        });
        return rows.map(([rowA, rowB]) => [
            ...rowA.slice(0, -1),
            ((rowB[0].width += rowA.at(-1).width - overlap), rowB[0]),
            ...rowB.slice(1)
        ]).concat(rowsA.slice(rows.length), rowsB.slice(rows.length));
    }

    function treeToLevels(root) {
        if (!root.children.length) { // leaf: one level.
            return [[root, new DisplayNode(1)]];
        } else {
            const levels = root.children.map(treeToLevels).reduce(mergePair);
            const width = getWidth(levels); // guaranteed to be odd >= 3
            root.width = (width >> 1) | 1;
            return [[root, new DisplayNode(width - root.width - 1)], ...levels];
        }
    }

    if (!tree) return "";
    return treeToLevels(new DisplayNode(tree)).map(row =>
        `<tr>${row.map(node => node.toHtml()).join("")}<\/tr>`
    ).join("\n");
}

// ---------------- Example run -----------------
function demo() {
    class Node {
        constructor(value, ...children) {
            this.value = value;
            this.children = children;
        }
    }

    const randint = (end) => Math.floor(Math.random() * end);
    const choose = arr => arr[randint(arr.length)];

    function randomTree(count, degree) {
        const root = new Node(randint(2000));
        let leaves = [root];
        while (count > 1) {
            const parent = choose(leaves);
            const numChildren = randint(Math.min(degree, count - 1)) + 1;
            count -= numChildren;
            parent.children = Array.from({length: numChildren}, () =>
                new Node(randint(2000))
            );
            leaves = leaves.filter(node => node != parent).concat(parent.children);
        }
        return root;
    }

    const root = randomTree(30, 6);
    document.querySelector(".graph").innerHTML = treeToHtml(root);
}

demo();
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", demo);
```

```css
.graph table, .graph { border-spacing: 0; }
.graph td { vertical-align: top; padding: 0; height: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; }
.graph td:empty { min-width: 10px }
.graph table td:not(:empty) { border-radius: 20px; background: pink; border: solid; padding: 10px; text-align: center; }
.graph table { width:100% }
.graph table td { width:50% }
.graph table td:nth-child(2) { border-left: solid; }
.graph .branch { border-top: solid; }
```

```html
<button>Randomize!</button>
<table class="graph"></table>
```